# getting data in oracle from 2 tables where no entries are guanranteed in one or both tables

Tags: c#, oracle, join

I'll simplify my existing example.
lets say I have

```
table1: with ID1, Car; ID2, Bus
```

and also

```
table2: with ID1, red; ID3, green
```

now I want to get everything for `ID1` which is simple:

```
select * from table1, table2 WHERE table1.ID = table2.ID AND table1.ID = 1
```

and I get `ID1, Car, red`.

but if I ask for `ID = 2`

I get nothing because of the missing entry in `table2` for `ID2`.
But I want all data for `ID2` (and also ID3) even if it has just data in 1 table.

I tried a `FULL JOIN` which gives me

`ID2, Bus`

But when I am trying to read those things in `C#`, I get `the datareader has no rows`, even while getting the answer in `Toad` for `Oracle`.

Comment: Full join is ok, and the result in Toad is a confirmation. Your C# code is wrong.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949197/isnt-sql-a-left-join-b-just-a/53949327

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `left join`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: I think you need a full outer join. See my comment above for a visualization