# How to join two tables with same ID?

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have two tables.

Table1:

| Schools | Type | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| school1 | A | CityA |
| school2 | B | CityB |

Table2:

| schools | population | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| school1 | 1000 | 01/01/2021 |
| school2 | 2000 | 01/02/2021 |
| school3 | 3000 | 01/03/2021 |

I want to figure out how to join them like below (without school3):

| schools | type | city | population | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| school1 | A | CityA | 1000 | 01/01/2021 |
| school2 | B | CityB | 2000 | 01/02/2021 |

I am a beginner and really confused about how to deal with this problem.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3eaf9/2

Comment: use [INNER JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

You should use JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.schools, t1.type, t1.city, t2.population, t2.time
FROM
  Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  Table2 t2 ON t1.schools = t2.schools
```

More information how JOIN works you can see in picture in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949197/isnt-sql-a-left-join-b-just-a)

Difference between INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?noredirect=1&lq=1)